# What Export Settings are required for Bootstrap Studio

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

for some reason, I cannot run PHP export scripts with `Bootstrap Studio`(Windows 10).
The message I get from `error.log` file is:

```
 Couldn't execute script C:\xampp\htdocs\Nuurdwind\export-test.php
```

What settings are required for the Export Options?
Are there any other settings that have to be considered?

Comment: A  work-around would be to call the php-file from within a batch-file.

Comment: Important: Set the working directory in the batch-file as BSS (vs. 5) does not set it.
See https://bootstrapstudio.io/forums/topic/how-to-run-php-export-script/ for more details and an example.